# PyCharm terminal installing packages into anaconda base instead of venv

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I can install modules on PyCharm through settings but I can't do my usual pip install  after installing anaconda. Now everytime I ask for a new module, it just installs it into the anaconda directory. All my scripts run with modules from the venv, but the PyCharm terminal is completely useless for modules. I've looked places saying to activate the environment with venv/scripts/activate but that has not done anything. What am I supposed to do to get the terminal to work again?

When I type 'python' in the PyCharm terminal, I get this:

```
Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```